# shell script quotation mark disappear

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script, and get the input parameters, like:

`./test abc def ghi`

If there is a `echo $*` inside the script, it would list down the parameters, however quotation marks disappear, like

`./test abc "def ghi"` --> abc def ghi

I dont want to run the command with back-slash as `./test abc \"def ghi\"`, although it could solve this problem. `echo $2` would not solve the quotation inside it, like `./test abc "def ghi "jkl" mno"`

Is there any other way to solve it? Thank you:)

Comment: why do you think you need to keep the literal quotation marks? What are you using $2 for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use single quotes:

```
./test abc '"def ghi"'
```

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you very much:)
Another problem, if there exist something complex inside it, how to deal with it? like `'"45 56 45 "78 \][s[df\s\d "\n\'''\ 5 6 "'`

Comment: I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but another way to deal with complicated quoting is to use [here documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by wrapping the double-quotes inside single quotes, like so:

```
./test abc '"def ghi"'
```

**Explanation:**

Everything enclosed by single-quotes is interpreted as string literals by shell. Here's some more information on [Strong Quoting vs. Weak Quoting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-1).